# Where can I ask a question about UK exam boards?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was considering Academia, however then I changed my mind because I am not sure if secondary school questions are on scope there.
Specifically, I have gained curiosity about how exams are checked - I heard from a teacher the papers are marked by a machine? - although I'm having problems with figuring out where this kind of question belongs.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Anything under university level is off-topic at academia (forgive me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @muddyfish you are right,as its ontopic there only if it's to achieve highter degree. removing my comment

Comment: So are there any similar sites which will accept my question?

Comment: I don't think so? (If there is could someone ping me?)